# How to PHPDoc a declarative array?

Tags: php, phpdoc

How i can create a PHPDoc block for an declarative array?.

For example, let's say that i have the next function:

```
/**
* @return ??????????
*/
function dummy() {
   $x1=array("key1"=>"hello","ke2"=>"world");
  return $x1;
}
// ... later
$x1=dummy();
echo $x1["key1"];
```

I want to be explicit in the array result, instead of use @return array.

(i also tried) I also know that i can return an array of object with @return Class[] but in this case, im not using classes.

Thanks.

Comment: No, you're not using classes, but your example shows strings so why not `@return string[]`?

Comment: Thanks Mark but i wish to use phpdoc for auto suggest me the key of the array.

Comment: @magallanes you can't use phpdoc for auto-key-suggestions.

Comment: If you need that degree of control, and your keys are fixed, then why not use an object with those fixed properties instead; then it can be suggested by an IDE